# Cargar pagina, con vídeo pausado en BOOTSTRAP

Tags: bootstrap, angular, video

Estoy haciendo una página web mediante angular y bootstrap. El problema es que al cargar un video mediante un **iframe**, el video se inicia y con sonido. lo cual es muy molesto.

Cómo puedo configurar los parámetros?

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 wow fadeInRight">
   <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="../../../assets/img/alfarim.mp4"</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Un poco extraño lo que te sucede, por lo general la reproducción automática de videos está bloqueada en la mayoría de los navegadores. Tienes un link dónde podamos ver lo que nos dices? También recuerda que debes cerrar el inicio de la etiqueta iframe, te falta `>` después de `/alfarim.mp4"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para configurar parametros de video puedes utilizar la etiqueta `<video>` de `HTML5`

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 wow fadeInRight">
    <video class="embed-responsive-item" src="../../../assets/img/alfarim.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
</div>
```

El atributo `autoplay` es para que reproduzca en automatico, `muted` para que sea sin sonido y `loop` para que se repita...